# Can I use variables within the data in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
// common.types
export const COMPONENT_TYPES = { TIME: "TIME" }

// App.vue
data: () => ({
  componentType: COMPONENT_TYPES.TIME
})
```

Sometimes undefined issues occur at very small frequencies. It's only like that in safari.

Below is an error message....

undefined is not an object (evaluating '*constants_design_types__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_["COMPONENT_TYPES"].TIME')

Answer (score 0):

That may be due to webpack. In theory you completely can do this, but I've already had this issue a few times with Webpack before, but I never had it again since I switched to Vite https://vitejs.dev/